# Get list of all databases that have a view named 'foo' in them

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a few servers that have a bunch of databases in them.
Some of the databases have a view called vw_mydata.

What I want to do is create a list of all databases containing a view named vw_mydata and then execute that view and store it's contents in a table that then contains al the data from all the vw_mydata.

I know I can find all the databases containing that view using

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS dbName from [?].sys.views where name like ''vw_mydata'''
```

But then I have as many recordsets as I have databases. How do I use that to loop through the databases?

What I would preferis a single neat list of the databasenames that I then can store in a resultset. Then it would be pretty straightforward.

I have thought about running above TSQL and storing the results in a table but I would like to keep it all in one SSIS package and not having all kind of tables/procedures lying around. Can I use a #table in a Execute SQL Task in SSIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Tsql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Tsql = ''

SELECT @Tsql = @Tsql + 'SELECT ''' + d.name + ''' AS dbName FROM [' + d.name + '].sys.views WHERE name LIKE ''vw_mydata'' UNION '
FROM master.sys.databases d

--"trim" the last UNION from the end of the tsql.
SET @Tsql = LEFT(@Tsql, LEN(@Tsql) - 6)

PRINT @Tsql

--Uncomment when ready to proceed
--EXEC (@Tsql)
```

Comment: This will only work as long as your account has access to every database on the system, FYI.

Comment: This works beautifully. We use an account thas has db_datareader on all databases. I changed a tiny detail: FROM master.sys.databases d WHERE d.state = 0. There are some databases offline, it crashed on them.

Comment: @Henrov, excellent point about offline db's.  You may also want to filter out system db's, db snapshots, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To use a temp table in SSIS, you'll need to use a global temp table (`##TABLE`).

On the properties for the connection, I'm pretty sure you'll need to set `RetainSameConnection` to `TRUE`.

On the SQL task after you create the temp table, you'll need to set `DelayValidation` to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanx, unfortunately, I can only mark one answer as THE answer but you deserved it as well for your info!