# Search Table for specific column name across multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am looking at about 200 databases, each have an, almost, uniform structure.

I am trying to search all the databases for 1 specific column in 1 specific table. If that column does not exist, then return the Database name.

I wrote a cursor to do this, but I am stuck on how to return the Database name.

```
set nocount on;   
DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR (150)
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name like ('B1%') --might need to exclude more dbs

OPEN c_db_names
FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0

begin
Exec('
 SELECT 'code for returning DB name goes here' 
        ,c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
        ,t.name AS 'TableName'    

 FROM '+  @db_name + '.sys.columns c
 JOIN '+  @db_name + '. sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
 WHERE 1=1 
    and c.name like %MyName%'    
     ')
  FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END    
CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

Any recommendations here or even thoughts on how to do this more efficiently? i am not a fan of cursors, but they have their uses.

Also, how the heck do I flip that "LIKE" to something more reasonable for what I want?

Comment: Here is a similar question with an answer that uses dynamic T-SQL:  [Get list of all databases that have a view named 'foo' in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428990/get-list-of-all-databases-that-have-a-view-named-foo-in-them/25429185#25429185)

Comment: I grabbed it, changed it up, and it ran perfectly. However I need to look only at 1 specific table, so I will sort out how to do that here in a minute